# c# 独自のエラーコードを持つ例外を作成したい

Tags: c#

タイトルの件、Exceptionを継承した独自の例外クラスを作成して、独自の例外をキャッチした側でエラーコードを取得したいです。

エラーコードは任意のコードとすることができることとします。

この場合どのような独自の例外クラスを作成すれば良いでしょうか？

自己レスです。こんな感じでしょうか？
    public CustomException (string message, string errorCode) : base(message)
    { 
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode; 
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

基本的には単に`Exception`型を継承すればよいです。エラーメッセージを変更したい場合はベースクラスの引数に渡します。

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException(int errorCode)
    // : base(ここでエラーメッセージを指定します)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int ErrorCode { get; }
}
```

なお守らなくてもあまり害のないお約束としては引数が`(string message, Exception innerException)`と`(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)`のコンストラクターをそれぞれ用意するというものがありますが、これらは必要になったら実装すればよいと思います。

Comment: messageを指定したい場合、コンストラクタを増やせば良いでしょうか？

Comment: @mame そこは設計次第ですが、私なら単に引数を増やしますね。また指定されたエラーコードに応じて例外型の内部でメッセージを決めるつくりもあり得ます。